# org.json.JSONException while ParsePush.subscribeInBackground

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

The problem is when I call ParsePush.subscribeInBackground method I get an error:

*Parse subscription error: bad json response: org.json.JSONException: Value Invalid of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject*

Example code attached below:

```
Parse.initialize(AnUtility.GetApplicationContex(), appId, dotNetKey);
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
       @Override
       public void done(ParseException e) {
         if (e == null) {          
               Log.d(TAG, "Successfully subscribed to Parse broadcast Push Notifications");
         } else {
               Log.e(TAG, "Parse subscription error: " + e.getMessage());
         }
      }
   });
```

There are some warnings in LogCat according to this issue:

```
01-25 14:21:46.057: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(3217): Cannot use GCM for push because the app manifest is missing some required declarations. Please make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root <manifest> element:
01-25 14:21:46.057: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(3217): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
01-25 14:21:46.057: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(3217): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
01-25 14:21:46.057: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(3217): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
01-25 14:21:46.057: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(3217): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
01-25 14:21:46.057: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(3217): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
01-25 14:21:46.057: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(3217): <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
01-25 14:21:46.057: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(3217): <permission android:name="com.myappbundle.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
01-25 14:21:46.057: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(3217): <uses-permission android:name="com.myappbundle.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
01-25 14:21:46.057: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(3217): Also, please make sure that these services and broadcast receivers are declared as children of the <application> element:
01-25 14:21:46.057: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(3217): <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
01-25 14:21:46.057: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(3217): <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
01-25 14:21:46.057: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(3217):   <intent-filter>
01-25 14:21:46.057: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(3217):     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
01-25 14:21:46.057: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(3217):     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
01-25 14:21:46.057: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(3217):     <category android:name="com.myappbundle" />
01-25 14:21:46.057: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(3217):   </intent-filter>
01-25 14:21:46.057: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(3217): </receiver>
```

My AndroidManifest.xml file contains next receivers:

```
<receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.androidnative.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.unionassets.android.plugin.preview" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and permissions:

```
<permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<permission android:name="com.unionassets.android.plugin.preview.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.unionassets.android.plugin.preview.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

I'am using Parse Android SDK 1.8.2 for now. In eralier 1.8.0 version same code worked well.
So, does it depends on Parse SDK version or there is something else in my code?

Looking forward for advice.
Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Alex.

Answer (score 0):

I have just had a very similar issue.
The solution (it turns out) was simple, but it was really nasty to track down:

The Application Id key was wrong!

I got the key from a colleague, and it turn out that one of us had chopped the first character while copying it :-(
Why Parse reported this as:

```
Parse subscription error: bad json response: org.json.JSONException: Value Invalid of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

seems totally counter-intuitive. I wish they'd made another exception, or at least returned an actual JSON string that can be seen by the developer, so the issue can be recognized as an initialization error, and not a parsing issue.

Double-check your keys and see if that solves the problem - as it did for me.